# How to filter in java streams using boolean condition?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to filter a list using boolean condition as below. But this does not work.

```
public void write(List<? extends Student> items) {
    List<Student> list = items.stream().filter( student -> 
          checkAge(student.getage())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    super.write(list);
 }

 public boolean checkAge(String age) {
    if (age.length() < 5 && age.length() > 60) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
 }
```

Comment: I also have to log if the condition does not return true.

Comment: what does not work with the shared code? are `checkLength` and `checkAge` supposedly the same?

Comment: `age.length() < 5 && age.length() > 60` will never evaluate to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quantity can never be less than `5` and greater than `60` at the same time. So, the following code doesn't make sense:

```
if (age.length() < 5 && age.length() > 60) {
    return false;
}
```

You would like to change it to something like:

```
if (age.length() < 5 || age.length() > 60) {
    return false;
}
```